# Is it possible to allow multiple VNC connections to a DomU?

Tags: xen, vnc

Is there a way to enable multiple vnc clients to connect to the same DomU using the Xen 4.0 built-in vnc server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. No - propably not with the built in server.
Yes - you can make it work by using vncproxy.